How can I properly model Triple-junction solar cell using pvlib?
I am a French master's student currently undertaking a research internship. My project focuses on modeling the operational behavior of a CPVT system under realistic conditions.
Currently, I am using PV_LIB for my PV cell modeling, specifically the CEC Module Model, which works well for single-junction cells listed in their database. However, for CPV modeling, it would be counterproductive to overlook the performance of multijunction cells.
I am therefore seeking to model, as simply yet realistically as possible, a conventional multijunction cell, such as the InGaP/GaAs/Ge, using pvlib as much as possible. My approach involves directly modeling the cell with three subcells in series, each represented by a single diode. I plan to obtain parameters (shunt resistance, series resistance, current, ideality factor, etc.) from literature sources, as some papers offer typical cell values at reference temperature.
I will then apply the De Soto method implemented in PV_LIB to extrapolate these parameters for my real-world conditions (irradiance and temperature).
Firstly, I would appreciate your thoughts on this approach.
Secondly, after modeling each subcell, I need to combine them to obtain a total power value for my multijunction cell. While functions like PV_LIB.max_power_point exist for single cells, I am unsure how to proceed with three subcells. Could you help me?
I went through a lot of literature already, but none advice me properly on my approach, and neither on how to proceed with computing the total output power of my triplejunction cell. I am seeking advice from pvlib support team for that matter, maybe there is already an alternative implemented but not yet available on pvlib, or something that I missed in pvlib.

This is not really a programming question, but you are likely to get friendly advice through the pvlib mailing list: pvlib-python@googlegroups.com

You might try https://github.com/NREL/PVcircuit
